# Focus skip to top image in VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have two `VerticalFieldManager` which are in `HorizontalFieldManager` to make two columns with images inside. Those images are able to focus ([Blackberry add border to image when focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400448/blackberry-add-border-to-image-when-focus/33478760#33478760)) with border, but there is one problem, when I scroll from right to left and opposite focus skip to the top image in `VerticalFieldManager` how to avoid it and skip to the nearest left/right image? Part responsible for adding images:

```
for(int i=0;i<15;++i){
        if(i%2==0){
            v1.add(tab[i]);
        }else{
            v2.add(tab[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because your managers can only enter focus from 2 directions. For a `HorizontalFieldManager` its left and right, while `VerticalFieldManager` is top and bottom. When you scroll in your horizontal manager to the left, you are moving in a -1 direction. This is then passed to your vertical manager, where -1 means that it gets focus from the bottom. Likewise when you move to the right, it is in the +1 direction and focuses from the top.

The best bet for you would be to listen for navigation movement (on the horizontal manager), and then focus the correct field programmatically.

```
HorizontalFieldManager horManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | USE_ALL_WIDTH | USE_ALL_HEIGHT)
{
    protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time)
    {
        if(dx > 0 && leftManager.isFocus()) // Moved right from the left manager
        {
            int index = leftManager.getFieldWithFocusIndex();
            rightManager.getField(index).setFocus();
            return true;
        }
        else if(dx < 0 && rightManager.isFocus())// Moved left from the right manager
        {
            int index = rightManager.getFieldWithFocusIndex();
            leftManager.getField(index).setFocus();
            return true;
        }

        return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
    }
};
```

This assumes that both vertical managers contain the same number of fields and only two columns. But with a little bit of work, you can make this method handle a dynamic number of vertical managers, and fields.